# Change the background color of a column in a grid

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, dynamics-ax-2012

I have following form and I want to change the background color of a column, based on the values of other columns;
[image]

In the orange columns, instead of displaying orange background, I want the cell color to be the RGB combo of Red, Green & Blue fields under COLOR ATTRIBUTES section.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's say that the control the background of which you need to change is named FirstFieldControl. Set its `AutoDeclaration` property to `Yes` and `BackgroundColor` to `Window background`.

Now you need to override the `displayOption` method on your datasource, e.g.:

```
public void displayOption(Common _record, FormRowDisplayOption _options)
{
    YourTable   yourTable   = _record;
    int         color;
    ;

    switch (yourTable.Name)
    {
         case 'Red' :
                 color = WINAPI::rgbCon2int([255, 0, 0]);
                 break;
         case 'Green' :
                 color = WINAPI::rgbCon2int([0, 255, 0]);
                 break;
         case 'Blue' :
                 color = WINAPI::rgbCon2int([0, 0, 255]);
                 break;
    }

    if (color)
    {
        _options.backColor(color);
        _options.affectedElementsByControl(FirstFieldControl.id());
    }
    else
    {
        super(_record, _options);
    }
}
```

This is just an example to give you an idea - don't copy-paste :)

It's easier to store the color value in the table, then the code will be much nicer.

**P.S.** If you're changing the colors run-time you might need to use the following piece of code to refresh the record:

```
yourTable_ds.clearDisplayOption(yourTable);
yourTable_ds.refresh();
```

Comment: This is the right answer. Just to add some extra information, overriding this method has a very bad impact on performance of forms with lots of rows, so do it if you really need it, but it's not recommended only for esthetical purposes.

Comment: To speed things up precompute the color values in the `init` method.

Answer (score 0):

I want to show variable color according to warehouse in on-hand form. If I override displayOption on inventdim datasource, it does get called. It does get called if I override InventSum datasource. But I cannot get the actual inventdim record. In this form, InventSum is master table, and InventDim is the joined child table.